# Calling a notebook from a different notebook

Tags: functions, programming, evaluation

Basically I have a notebook (let's call it nb1) that when evaluated yields **one** number when I specify some parameter $\alpha$ (in nb1). I want to call nb1 in a different notebook (nb2) using for instance the NotebookEvaluate function, such that I can use the value calculated in nb1 in my second notebook nb2. Is there a neat way to do this, that also allows me to evaluate nb1 for different values of $\alpha$?

For concreteness I would like to do something like this in nb2:

```
tab = Table[NotebookEvaluate[nb1],{alpha,1,1000}];
```

**My question is:** What do I have to write in nb1 to run the table command as above?

I hope the above pseudocode illustrates what I want to do clearly.

I do not want to convert nb1 to a function, because the notebook is so long that I'm bound to run into a bunch of unforseen errors.

Comment: do not use N as a parameter, this is a function `N[expr]` gives the numerical value of `expr`. if you evaluated nb1 and then nb2, all data from nb1 is available in nb2.

Comment: Is there something specific I must write in nb1 to store the values in nb2? At the moment i've written    s =NotebookEvaluate[
  directory" <> "QuantumScattering.nb", 
  InsertResults -> True]; in nb2 but s does not contain the outputs of nb1

Comment: It is possible that in nb2 there are commands like `ClearAll[f] ,Clear[f]` for the parameter `f` being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the following in NB2,

```
Get["file directory path//file name of NB1"]
```

All the definitions calculated in NB1 will be available within NB2. Then you can do the calculations in NB2.